# How to adjust widht of a fixed element for a navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a fixed navigation bar + logo.
When set to 100%, the width is larger than the width of `<body>`. [See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PeBE.jpg)
*N.B. Let's ignore for a sec the problem that the navigation bar overlaps the image. I am tackling one thing at a time*

This was expected since fixed elements are placed outside the flow. Hence 100% is relative to the browser and not other elements.

2 QUESTIONS:

1. How can I avoid this and  having the same width of `<body>`? I have already tried to use the `inherit` attribute with no success
2. If the fixed elements are removed from the flow of the HTML, why does `<nav>` take into account the 8px standard margin from `<body>` on the left (see picture)? Shouldn't this place at the top-left corner?

CODE

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#NavBar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #8FAADC;
}

.NavBarElements {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  width: 16.6%;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.NavBarElements a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img id="MainLogo" src="pic/logohome.png" alt="Logo">
  <ul id="NavBar">
    <li class="NavBarElements">Item 1</li>
    <li class="NavBarElements">Item 2</li>
    <li class="NavBarElements">Item 3</li>
    <li class="NavBarElements">Item 4</li>
    <li class="NavBarElements">Item 5</li>
    <li class="NavBarElements">Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#NavBar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #8FAADC;
}

.NavBarElements {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  width: 16.6%;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.NavBarElements a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Silikhe but I don't want to remove the 8px margin of <body>. I want the navbar to have that one as well while being fixed on top and responsive

Answer (score 0):

You can use `calc()`:

```css
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#NavBar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #8FAADC;
}

.NavBarElements {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    width: calc(16.6% - (16px / 6));
    font-size: 12px;
}

.NavBarElements a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <img id="MainLogo" src="pic/logohome.png" alt="Logo">
    <ul id="NavBar">
        <li class="NavBarElements">Item 1</li>
        <li class="NavBarElements">Item 2</li>
        <li class="NavBarElements">Item 3</li>
        <li class="NavBarElements">Item 4</li>
        <li class="NavBarElements">Item 5</li>
        <li class="NavBarElements">Item 6</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks Spectric, that sounds an interesting thing to try but unfortunately everytime I try to add the Calc() function this is not rendered in the browser (I am using mozilla). Will keep on trying with your suggestion: probably I am doing something wrong